# Configuring a network interface as a IO port on Linux Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

I was wondering if it is possible to configure a network interface port to be used as a I/O Serial port in Fedora 13 Linux. If so does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this or point me in the direction of some info on the net?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configuring a network interface as a IO port on Linux Fedora](http://serverfault.com/questions/242069/configuring-a-network-interface-as-a-io-port-on-linux-fedora)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is **NO**.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [this](http://goo.gl/OCmOQ).  This particular device has multiple serial ports, and connects to a host computer running Linux over the network.  A kernel driver on the host makes it appears as if the host actually has multiple serial ports.  We use something like this for remote console access.

There are similar products from a variety of manufacturers.

Comment: This is not really what I am looking to do sorry.

Comment: And yet, it's exactly what you were asking!  If you want a different answer, you should probably try to clarify your question.

Comment: No I am looking for a software solution hence the question not an additional piece of hardware.