# Configuring a network interface as a IO port on Linux Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Configuring a network interface as a IO port on Linux Fedora](https://serverfault.com/questions/241725/configuring-a-network-interface-as-a-io-port-on-linux-fedora)

I was wondering if it is possible to configure a network interface port to be used as a I/O Serial port in Fedora 13 Linux. If so does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this or point me in the direction of some info on the net?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching for this same thing yesterday and found that the ser2net package can do exactly what you want.  After some testing, I did find some problems with its implementation of the Serial Control Protocol (RFC 2217) but, ignoring that, it does an admirable job.

I was working with debian linux and was able to find a package named "ser2net".  I would assume that Fedora has the same package available.  If not, it can be downloaded in source form from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ser2net/